# FileNotFound Error but file do exists and path are valid in AWS EC2 Instances

Tags: python, amazon-ec2

I was trying to read the file in AWS EC2 instances.

The cat commond goes alright.
[cat is good](https://i.stack.imgur.com/naoOK.png)
But the with open can not find the file.

[python open is wrong](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xsoEu.png)

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

prob_path = './proData.txt'

with open(prob_path) as f:
    probs_by_bits = f.readline().strip().split(' ')
    print(probs_by_bits)
```

But I do notice that this error occurs occiassionally. So I want to find out why this queation can happen

Any help would be appreciated!!

Besh wishes,

Rui Liu

I tried the cat command, head commond, it all works good, while the python script would encounter some IO error.

Comment: what does `ls -la coded-comp` tell you - do you see both files in the directory?

Comment: I change the relative path to the absolute path, and this question can be solved.

Comment: Anyway, A lot thanks, @rv.kvetch